# how to completley hide div (including column headings) in php report (if all div input value are null or 0. )

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, show-hide

I am displaying php report in div. If div have no data to display or 0 value then I want that whole div should be hide from the report.Here is my php report code in two div

```
                        <div class = "abc">
                      echo '<table class="styled-table">';
                            echo "<thead>";
                                echo "<tr>";                                  
                                   
                echo "<th>Name</th>";
                echo "<th>Phone</th>";
                echo "<th>Age</th>";        
                                   
                                    echo "<th>Action</th>";
                                echo "</tr>";
                            echo "</thead>";
                            echo "<tbody>";
                            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
                                echo "<tr>";                                       
                                    echo "<td>" . $row['pname'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['phone1'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['age'] . "</td>";                
                                 
                                    echo "<td>";  </div>
```

Comment: use mysqli_num_rows to check how many rows were returned, before you start to echo the div

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? How is this problem related to Javascript or [tag:show-hide]?

Answer (score 1):

You can add if else condition

```
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {

  your code

} else {
  don't display the div here
}
```